# plugin playing video in the pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Does anyone know a good plug-in that can help me accomplish the following:
I have a picture on a website. As soon as this picture is clicked the video player is open in the center of the screen. The video is played from youtube. Here is the website that represents exactly what I want - http://thumb.it/ (see video picture on the right side under the `watch our video` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this exact thing several years ago, using the jQuery fancyBox plugin (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). There very well may be better popup/modal window alternatives by now, although I was satisfied with fancyBox as it was very easy to work with.

FancyBox solves the problem of displaying the popup when the video thumbnail link is clicked. Inside fancyBox, you can embed the YouTube video (or HTML, or an image, or anything - not just videos).

Directly on the fancyBox documentation page, they link to this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/, which demonstrates how to launch a YouTube video from a popup link. The fiddle also demonstrates how to use the YouTube API to go to the next video when the first is finished playing.

Here's the JsFiddle code:

HTML

```
<!-- This loads the YouTube IFrame Player API code -->
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">Video #1</a>

<br />

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cYplvwBvGA4?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">Video #2</a>
```

JavaScript

```
// Fires whenever a player has finished loading
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// Fires when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // Go to the next video after the current one is finished playing
    if (event.data === 0) {
        $.fancybox.next();
    }
}

// The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    // Initialise the fancyBox after the DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect  : 'none',
                prevEffect  : 'none',
                padding     : 0,
                margin      : 50,
                beforeShow  : function() {
                    // Find the iframe ID
                    var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');

                    // Create video player object and add event listeners
                    var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });

}
```

CSS

```
.fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;       
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I can see fancyBox is for non-commercial use only. I need something open-source

Comment: I've also heard good things about SimpleModal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), but really any up-to-date modal plugin will have the same idea - pop up a box you can put HTML or embed a video in. Using the YouTube video embed guide here by say, putting the iframe inside the modal (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player), it shouldn't be too difficult to embed a video in whichever modal solution you choose.